QGIS Autofill form with last value of each object by using array_last
In my table I have saved all surveys of my trees. Each Survey contains the BA_ID, which is the unique identifier of the tree.

If I create a new survey using the form (see picture 2), I want to autofill values, if a tree already has been looked at before. For example, in the last survey the tree showed damage at the roots and I noted that down (using the chechbox, saved in a boolean field) and now I want to autofill that value when creating a new survey.

So I basically need a function which gets all values which belong to the same tree (->have the same BA_ID), orders them by date and picks the latest one. I used the following function for this
array_last( 
    array_agg (
    BA_WU_VERL, #boolean value if root has any damage
    group_by:=BA_ID, 
    order_by:=BA_KO_DA1 #date of the survey
)
)

This seems to work, as  I am getting an output.

But it does not work in the form, so if i create a new survey, it isnt autofilled. If I use a string as a field instead of a boolean, the correct value is displayed and autofilled. Do I need to convert the result of my function even though it outputs "true" and "false" (which are boolean values). If yes, how can i convert my function to be used with other datatypes besides strings.
Honestly I dont want to use string for every field, especially if it is a simple "true"/"false" checkbox.
I also have the same problem with another field that is an 32-bit integer, where the function returns only numbers but still wont work except when using a string as the data type.
